# How to replace a pattern by a pattern in VIM

Tags: regex, vim, replace

For example, if I want to replace all uppercase letter by its smallcase brother, how can I do?

Obviously 
`:%s/[A-Z]/[a-z]/g`
won't do, since it will take all the uppercases letter and turn them into ... [a-z]...

PS : It is just an example, so it is not a duplicate of how to lower cases...

In fact I want to replace all "X. Name" pattern by "X.~Name", so I want to replace a pattern to another pattern.

Comment: Try `:%s/[A-Z]/\L&/g`

Comment: You don't need a regex. Visual select your text then do `u`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret It is absolutely not a duplicate of the question you found ; my question was "how to replace a pattern by a pattern" with an example who happened to be uppercases to lowercases, but please see my PS. edit ; "How to only lowercase quoted string in VIM " doesn't answer at all my question...

Comment: Seriously, you can't infer how to solve your problem from the linked answer ? *"You can also use the \L atom to turn the string after it to lower case"*.

Comment: *replace all "X. Name" pattern by "X.~Name"* is a totally different question (and a simpler one, you just need to know how to refer to submatch, ie with \1, \2, etc.).

Comment: As already told (see answer and comments), of course you can replace a pattern by another pattern in vim. I don't know your exact requirement (you'd need to write it clearly) but you can do for example `:%s/\v(\w+)\.(\w+)/\1.\~\2`.

Comment: If you need more explanations go to the SO/JavaScript chat or to https://dystroy.org/miaou/3

Comment: @DenysSéguret Ok, thank you for your additional explanation, I think I got it better, thanks to it.